# How to get client id and client secret dynamically from request header?

Tags: c#, header

I'm trying to get client id and client secret dynamicaly without passing string parameter of `"xyzClientId"` and `"xyzClientSecret"`

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {            

            bool isTenantForbidden = false;

            var headers = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers;
            headers.Add("xyzClientId", "someclientId");
            headers.Add("xyzClientSecret", "someClientSecret");           

            headers.TryGetValue("xyzClientId", out var clientId);
            headers.TryGetValue("xyxClientSecret", out var clientSecret);

            var tenant = this.tenantService.GetTenant(clientId, clientSecret);
            
            isTenantForbidden = await this.ForbidTenant(tenant);            

            if (isTenantForbidden)
            {
                throw new Exception("Restricted resource!");
            }

            await next();
        }
```

How I get these access informations like getting Bearer token:

```
context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out authorizationToken);
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: I'm trying to get client id and client secret via   
var headers = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionExecutingContext.context.HttpContext.Request.Headers;